# Join separate integer values to form a whole number

Tags: c

The thing I am trying to achieve is given by the following code:

```
int a = 2, b = 7, c = 5, d = 0, e = 9;
int x = 27509; /* aka a + b + c + d + e */
```

What would be a way to do this?

Comment: That's a good idea. But I am working with huge 5 to 6 figure random numbers! Would there be a more efficient way? Thanks!

Comment: question makes lacks sufficient context. Also, when did a 6 digit number become huge. It isn't!

Comment: Then specify your problem more clearly.

Comment: @antikbd There's not really a "more efficient" way than simply multiplying and adding'em. Anyway, why do you think that this method is "inefficient"? Or that even if it is, you *need* a more efficient way? Is this causing a measurable performance bottleneck in your code? No? Then don't bother.

Comment: (((a*10+b)*10 + c)*10 + d)*10 + e is the most efficient way I can think of.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the responses! Sorry if this was a stupid question - I am just beginning to learn C! Once again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user3121023 That's really inefficient. sprintf and strtol are very slow functions (comparing with multiply and add).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
  int nums[5] = {2,7,5,0,9};
  long long sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) 
    sum = sum * 10 + nums[i];
  // print: sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x = 10; x < 1000000000; x++){
  if(b < x){
     c = a*x + b;
     break;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
char str[80];
char stringNum[20];
char *success;

success = malloc(20 * sizeof(*success));

sprintf(stringNum, "%d", a);    // converts int a into a string
strcpy(str, stringNum);         // initializes str
sprintf(stringNum, "%d", b);
strcat(str, stringNum);

printf("%ul", strtol(str, &success, 10)); // you'll get an int 23
free(success);
```

Just modify the values of the int variables to suit your needs and concatenate them to str.

Comment: -1, why solve a math problem using strings? Also, that painterman's algorithm with repeated `strcat`ting hurts my brain.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant antikbd did not ask for an optimal solution. So I gave other ways to do so.